# FormData append is an empty object after appending a file

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

This is the file I try to append and send to the server (console.log):

```
...
console.log(myFile); // brings this:

File(1921512) {name: "2018-10-07_23-53-14.png", lastModified: 1538945346813, lastModifiedDate: Sun Oct 07 2018 23:54:06 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1921512, …}
lastModified: 1538945346813
lastModifiedDate: Sun Oct 07 2018 23:54:06 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time) {}
name: "2018-10-07_23-53-14.png"
size: 1921512
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

I append this file like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append(0, myFile);
```

Then I do:

```
console.log(formData); // FormData {}__proto__: FormData
```

There no files appended in there.

When I am trying to send this to server the content type of the Http request headers is just not contain any content type:

Request headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6,la;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

I have tried to log this with entities but this still not working - anyway the server doesn't get any files.

Comment: Did you try:
formData.append("my-file", new Blob([myFile], { type: "image/png" }));

Answer (score 0):

I have added: `transformRequest: angular.identity` in the request params.